# How to give root privileges to a normal user using chef cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, root, aix, cookbook

How to give root privileges to a normal user using chef cookbook.
Hi, i have a user as tempuser and i want to give the user root privileges.
Please let me know how it can be done using chef cookbook.

Comment: Try the [sudo](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/sudo) cookbook, along with [sudo_rules](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/sudo_rules) if you have something complex to do.

Answer (score 1):

Something integrating with sudo would be the normal approach, exactly how you do it is up to you. There is a community [sudo cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/sudo) available.